# Django: Model class X doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

He looked for other solutions in stackoverflow but did not get it.

The structure of my project is the following:

```html
src
|
|---project
         |
         | settings.py
         | apps
             |
             |
             __init__.py
             app1
              |.....
             app2
             app3
```

```
My settings.py 

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'project.apps.App1Config',
'project.apps.App2Config',
'project.apps.App3Config',
'project.apps.App4Config',
'project.apps.ProjectConfig',)


apps/__init__.py

class App1Config(AppConfig):
        name = 'project.apps.app1'
        verbose_name = "App"
```

And still appears in console:

> RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class project.models.Model
>   doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an
>   application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its
>   application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django
>   1.9.
>
> RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class
>   project.apps.app1.models.Model doesn't declare an explicit
>   app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else
>   was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be
>   supported in Django 1.9.

Comment: try it without "project".

Comment: It doesn't work:
ImportError: No module named 'apps'

Comment: if you have migrations, check if the import statements are correct and if they are pointing to the full path of the model

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your app's name like this:

```
class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = '**app1**'
    verbose_name = "App"
```